# How to align dropdown menu right underneath nav item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to attempt to align the "Big Dropdown" midmenu right below the actual Nav Item instead of opening off-screen like it does now, pretty sure i'm just missing something but would like to achieve this in the cleanest way possible.

**HTML**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" 
    id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Big Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu midmenu ">
        <div class="row">
            <li class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
nav.main .megamenu {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav.main .midmenu {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Codepen** - Please See "Big Dropdown"
https://codepen.io/GH5ST/pen/GGgWPK

Comment: Like [this](https://codepen.io/sayob/pen/aKzWag) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me, I gave the big dropdown a new class and adjusted the `margin` and `absolute` position.  (copy and paste into your Codepen to try):

```
    <nav class="sub">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <div class="dropdown mr-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Select Website
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Select Country
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm ml-auto">Search</button>
                        <div class="dropdown ml-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                                My Account
                            </button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown ml-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button">
                                1-800-MELISSA
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light main bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Mega Dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
                            <div class="row">
                                <li class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Big Dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu bigmenu ">
                            <div class="row">
                                <li class="col-md-6">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-md-6">
                                    <ul>
                                        <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Normal Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</header>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700,800|Roboto:300,400,400i,500,500i,700");
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
header .container-fluid {
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Navigation Sub
------------------------------------- */
nav.sub {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Navigation Main
------------------------------------- */
nav.main {

}
nav.main .nav-logo {
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
nav.main ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* ------ Mega Menu ------ */
nav.main .megamenu {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* ------ Mid Menu ------ */
nav.main .midmenu {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav.main .bigmenu {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: ;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 50em;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,400i,600,700,800|Roboto:300,400,400i,500,500i,700");
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

header .container-fluid {
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Navigation Sub
------------------------------------- */

nav.sub {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 10px 0;
}


/* Navigation Main
------------------------------------- */

nav.main {}

nav.main .nav-logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav.main ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* ------ Mega Menu ------ */

nav.main .megamenu {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* ------ Mid Menu ------ */

nav.main .midmenu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  float: left;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light main bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Mega Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
              <div class="row">
                <li class="col-md-3">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-3">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Big Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu midmenu ">
              <div class="row">
                <li class="col-md-6">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-6">
                  <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Normal Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="sub">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="dropdown mr-2">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
         Select Website
        </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
         Select Country
        </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm ml-auto">Search</button>
            <div class="dropdown ml-2">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
         My Account
        </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown ml-2">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" type="button">
         1-800-MELISSA
        </button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```